How could some verses such as Matthew 18:11 have been added to some translations?
I’m trying to answer that question properly but I can’t find a better answer than using the history of the preservation itself

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Hi Roney, welcome to the site! This question doesn't really show any research effort and is likely to accrue downvotes, there's a Low Quality flag that somebody's raised against it. I'd suggest updating the body of your Question, perhaps citing the verse in full and explaining where you're currently at in your research about it.

It looks like you are asking about textual criticism, For a good question, you need to cite the specific verses so we know the specific text you refer to. You could also ask for the pros and cons of accepting the text in question. Make sure the body of your question includes the main question, not only in the title.

Roney, It would be better to ask a neutral question such as "What evidence was used to determine that Matthew 18:11 should be excluded from many translations?" Then, in the body of your question, quote the original verse, noting that it's not present in many modern translations. And finally, perhaps note which translations still include it. Incidentally, these are called "interpolations."

Here is Bruce Metzger's commentary answering your question.

  18:11      omit verse {B}



There can be little doubt that the words ἦλθεν γὰρ ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ ἀνθρώπου (ζητήσαι καὶ) σῶσαι τὸ ἀπολωλός are spurious here, being absent from the earliest witnesses representing several textual types (Alexandrian, Egyptian, Antiochian), and manifestly borrowed by copyists from Lk 19:10. The reason for the interpolation was apparently to provide a connection between ver. 10 and verses 12–14.
--
Metzger, B. M., United Bible Societies. (1994). A textual commentary on the Greek New Testament, second edition a companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament (4th rev. ed.) (p. 36). United Bible Societies.


+1. Good, simple, direct answer.  Sometimes these additions are taken from the Vulgate where many such exist and a few ended up back in the Greek.
